# Semantic UI - Sidebar toggle always return page to top

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I have created sidebar with semantic ui, but when i scroll down the page and toggle sidebar my page always return to top. Just to be clear, i have position: fixed nav with button that toggle sidebar so i need page to stay in same place when i toggle sidebar on.

HTML

```
<div class="ui left vertical menu sidebar slide along">
<h3 class="sidebar-heading">Menu</h3>
<a class="item">
  SIDEBAR ITEM
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pull-right"></i>
</a>
<a class="item">
  SIDEBAR ITEM
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pull-right"></i>
</a>
<a class="item">
  SIDEBAR ITEM
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pull-right"></i>
</a>
<a class="item">
  SIDEBAR ITEM
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pull-right"></i>
</a>
<a class="item">
  SIDEBAR ITEM
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pull-right"></i>
</a>
```

```
<div class="pusher">
   <a href="#" class="menu-trigger"></a>
</div><!-- ENd of pusher -->
```

JS

```
$('.menu-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
});
```

Comment: I was using `a` tag instead of `button` so that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
.pusher { min-height: 100% !important; height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: Yea i used a tag for menu-trigger, i am idiot i know :) So i just used button instead. But i had other problem with elements with background-attachment: fixed so i just gave up on sidebars. Thanks for answer anyway.